# Google charts: Remove space between in boxes in bars of histogram

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, histogram

How do we remove the white space in each bar ?

[image]

```
var options = {
      title: '     Annual Disbursement Chart',
      'titleTextStyle': { color: 'black', fontSize: 10, bold: true  },
      'vAxis': {'title': 'Number of Values' },
      'hAxis': {'title': 'Annual Disbursements',baselineColor: 'black'},
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      width: 300,

    };
```

Comment: There is no way to remove that space from the individual points in a histogram stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `stroke-width: 2; stroke-color: fill-color;` in the `{role: 'annotation'}` column